# How to convert my music to ringtones for the Iphone 5

Tags: iphone, itunes, ringtones

I am trying to convert some of my favourite music files to ringtones on my iPhone 5. It has been pretty confusing maneuvering iTunes to do so, so I'm looking for a much easier way to do so.

I connect my iPhone (iOS 6.0.2) to a PC running iTunes 11.0.1.12.

Answer (score 1):

GarageBand can do it. Import a song, select a 30-second range, export it as a ringtone.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1358

Edit:just saw the PC bit.

Haven't tried it, but there's an app: 
https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/ringtone-maker-make-free-ringtones/id390929278?mt=8

And a website: www.iringer.net/

Answer (score 0):

I use Rogue Amoeba's [Fission](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CD8QjBAwBA&url=http://rogueamoeba.com/fission/&ei=A08TUZ2JNaqa0QWjtIHQBQ&usg=AFQjCNGx97b37vZqG9xlIjIBCX7Rnr771w&sig2=uNYlUm9GDFJxXB42N14rtg&bvm=bv.42080656,d.d2k). It's not cheap, but it's useful for all kinds of audio editing, and it makes ringtones very easily.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this tutorial, it walks you through it. http://www.gottabemobile.com/2011/10/26/ios-5-how-to-create-custom-ringtones-and-alerts-for-the-iphone/