# custom ringtone on iphone5s using linux?

Tags: itunes, unix, iphone, ringtones

I have an iPhone 5s. I want to have my own custom ringtone on my iPhone.

But is there any way to do this without the (really time consuming) way of starting up computer, start iTunes, connect iPhone and sync the ringtone. And then set the ringtone as default.

I am running Linux so iTunes does not work anyway it would on a windows computer.

I connected my iPhone to my linux computer (elementary os). I saw a lot of directories which I do not see on a windows computer:

- Books
- Cloudassets
- DCIM
- Downloads
- iTunes_Control
- LoFiCloudAssets
- PhotoData
- Photos
- Podcasts
- Purchases
- Radio
- Recordings

I was thinking if it might be possible to get my ringtone on my iphone using one of these directories...

Is there a solution for this?

I have read this question:

[How to convert my music to ringtones for the Iphone 5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81331/how-to-convert-my-music-to-ringtones-for-the-iphone-5)

But the tutorial mentioned over there implies working with either a Mac or Windows computer and having iTunes.

And I have also read this question:

[Can I add a custom ringtone to my iPhone without syncing to iTunes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38063/can-i-add-a-custom-ringtone-to-my-iphone-without-syncing-to-itunes)

And a google search brought me a shenzhen iphone app which should be able to import a ringtone from dropbox but then still needs iTunes to sync the ringtone to my iPhone.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38069/85275 has the answer… No, it cannot be done because of the way iOS sandboxes

Comment: Thanks. Another reason for me not to buy an iPhone again (though my employer supplied the Phone to me).

Comment: Your call. Seems rather a trivial reason to me, but I don't use nix with my phones, only on work machines, so I just hook up to my Mac to do anything like that; 30s operation.

Comment: I know. If it was only this, it would be trivial. But this issue is one of many I have. Apple somehow opened up a little for other developers in iOs 8, so finally I have swype available (I had it like years ago on my Android). It is also the integration of other apps (simply sharing a picture with whatsapp from the gallery is not among the options offered by iOS). But to sum up: Apple thinks it knows the best what is good for me. But they do not. And I hate that arrogance. So my next Phone is an Android Phone which offers me much more integration and flexibility.

Answer (score -2):

The ringtone folder is under iTunes_Control